# APPLE TV and the Bluetooth keyboard (Youtube playlist video skip)

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, appletv, playlist

While watching Youtube playlists on my Apple TV need to know how to jump/or skip to the next one using my Logitech Bluetooth K480 keyboard. It appears that F6 and F8 keys were supposed to do this but they do NOT work. There's very little info on this presently; so please if anyone has figured out how, please let me know!!

Mr. Phil

Comment: If it's any consolation, I couldn't find a way to do this with an Apple keyboard paired with the Apple TV (3), either. The closest thing I could find was to press return, down arrow, return.  So, it takes three keys rather than one.

Comment: Thanks! It is a consolation and I'm suspicious that they will not fix generation three. However, I submitted a request/feedback at Youtube for a fix on this. Will post here once a fix has been achieved or new information breaks forth.  Onward and upward!